# combine rasters into single raster with multiple field values in R

Tags: raster, r

I have several raster brick objects that I would like to combine into one raster with multiple field values for each cell, but I am not sure how to do this in R.

For example, let's say I have two layers in a 2*2 raster brick.

```
r <-raster(nrow=2,ncol=2)
r[] <- round(runif(ncell(r))* 10,0)
s <-raster(nrow=2,ncol=2)
s[] <- round(runif(ncell(r))* 10,0)
t = brick(r,s)
```

I would like to combine the values for r and s into a single raster with multiple values (at the object@data@attributes slot, I think) associated with each cell.

So, in the above example, if cell 1 = 1 in r and cell 1 = 2 in s, then the output that I desire is that the resulting raster contain two fields at @data@attributes, the first field = 1 and the second field = 2.

Answer (score 5):

If you would like to keep the object type(s) as raster I would take a look at the ratify function although, I do not think that it is intended for numeric data.

```
require(raster)
r2 <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
  r2[] = 1
    r2[51:100] = 2
      r2[3:6, 1:5] = 3

r2 <- ratify(r2)
  rat <- levels(r2)[[1]]
    rat$MyRATValue <- c(100,200,300)
      rat$code <- c(1,2,3)
        levels(r2) <- rat
          r2
```

You could also coerce the raster brick object to a SpatialPixelsDataFrame object where the @data slots holds attributes for each raster. This is however, not necessarily memory safe.

```
require(raster)
r <-raster(nrow=2,ncol=2)
  r[] <- round(runif(ncell(r))* 10,0)
  s <-raster(nrow=2,ncol=2)
    s[] <- round(runif(ncell(r))* 10,0)
      r = brick(r,s)

r <- as(r, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame")
  str(r@data)
    head(r@data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about using t as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I have figured out a way to do it.

```
r <-raster(nrow=2,ncol=2)
r[] <- round(runif(ncell(r))* 10,0)
s <-raster(nrow=2,ncol=2)
s[] <- round(runif(ncell(r))* 10,0)
u <-raster(nrow=2,ncol=2)
u[] <- round(runif(ncell(r))* 10,0)
u = brick(u,r,s)
u@data@attributes[1][[1]] <- values(u)
```

At least in the toy example this does what I wanted it to do.

Comment: So, the question here is what are you going to do with this? Since raster objects operate in a different way the sp objects, I am not clear on the intention. You have just negated the memory safe aspects of a raster object and are storing the value attributes twice. With this solution, you may as well coerce to an sp object and operate directly on the pixels in a given function.

Comment: BTW, you should check the validity of this solution. Since the placeholder class for this empty slot is list(), I would imagine that any functions intended for this slot is depending on this specific object class.

Comment: I am basically trying to create a raster file similar to the National Land Cover Dataset (USGS) or NatureServe's natural areas raster file. These raster files have attribute tables associated with each cell. I agree that this may create issues, but can't come up with another way. That is the reason I posted the question.

Comment: You are right, I was able to create it in the toy data set but it doesn't match what is in the National Landcover Dataset and the NatureServe natural community data.

Comment: For NLCD the bit-depth creates a 0-255 range of values but only certain values are related to landcover classes. All yo need to do is to turn non-attributed values to NA. Since the numeric values are nationally consistent, you do not need the text attributes. I am not sure why you have multiple bands, unless the data is multi-year, it should be a single band not RGB.

Comment: Sorry, I am not being clear on what I am doing. I only gave the NLCD as an example. I have multiband climate data, with each band representing a single GCM output for a month. I want to be able to easily see the values in ArcGIS using an attribute table, rather than switching between individual bands. But this is getting off topic. If there isn't a way to do it, let's just leave it at that. But if there isn't, then the @data@attributes slot seems of limited use.