# Seeking methodology in R similar to ArcGIS Combine?

Tags: r

Is there a way/tool in R that could produce similar output as ArcGIS "Combine" tool does?

Comment: If you have ArcGIS installed on your machine, you may try using [R-ArcGIS bridge](https://github.com/R-ArcGIS/r-bridge).Otherwise try using the `library(rgdal)` or other, check these out [Merging multiple rasters in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876591/merging-multiple-rasters-in-r) or [combine rasters into single raster with multiple field values in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/126811/combine-rasters-into-single-raster-with-multiple-field-values-in-r)

Comment: Could you tell us what "Combine" does, or point us to documentation?

Comment: The combine tool is explained here: https://pro.arcgis.com/fr/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/combine.htm

Comment: Okay that looks simple enough in R. If you can summarise that in your question and create some sample rasters (maybe like the ones in the Arc docs) I'll answer. Have flagged to re-open.